# Check if file exists AND is greater than

Tags: php, file

I need to check if a file in the same folder as the script exists and is greater than 100 Bytes, if so echo "is there".

Comment: I would say split that question into its two parts and Google both of them. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: check my answer to Winter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're trying to do something like this:

```
$filename = 'test.txt';

if (file_exists($filename) && filesize($filename) > 100) {
    echo "is there";
} else {
    echo "not there";
}
```

Read the PHP documentation of [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) and [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: I allready tried similar code and yours too but it is not working, may be because the file don't have an extension? the name is "markefarbeblausortseite"

Comment: Have you tried [glob](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) / [preg_grep](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) / [scandir](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) etc. to find the file?

Comment: It's allready solved, some other PHP code made trouble ^^ thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
if(file_exists($filename) && filesize($filename) >100){
  echo "is there";
}
```